How to run service associated with child after creating parent
In my Rails/React project, I have a parent class called "Projects".  Projects accept nested attributes for Cabinets via an API call.  Projects have many Cabinets.
When I create a project via API, I'm also simultaneously creating the first cabinet object in that same API call.  After the cabinet is saved, I'd like to run a job, which I inserted into the Cabinets controller's create action:
ShelfPartsJob.perform_later(@cabinet.id, 'CREATE')

The issue is this job only runs when I create a standalone Cabinet object.  If I create a cabinet through the project, it doesn't run.
Any suggestions on how to run this job when the project is created?  It requires the @cabinet.id value in order to run.

Maybe move this to the Cabinet model using one of its callbacks like after_create?

@engineersmnky I'll attempt that approach.  Thanks!

Callbacks (in the model) are the standard way to do it.

@engineersmnky the callback in the model succeeded.  This is the way. Thanks!

call job next line after creating project/cabinet
